# Differences between a 100 point grading scale, 10 point grading scale and a 5 point grading scale?

Tags: ranking

If I am ranking a set of items based on their performance on a set of categories (each of which has a different importance, or weight, in the total score).

What are the pros and cons of a 100 point grading scale for grading the items vs. an alternative scale, when the purpose of the ranking is to dispose of those items that are ranked last (i.e. have a poor score).